# Unimaginable mod 34

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm currently studying on the modulo n when I encounter this kind of problem,,, my basic doesn't suffice the requirement to solve this problem... Please help me with this one. 
Find the least modulo 34 of $$(2^{40})(15^{100}) - (63)(130^{2})$$

Comment: HINT: you need Chinese Remainder Theorem and $34=2 \cdot 17$.

Comment: Do you mean "residue" when you say "primitive root"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT.-$$63\cdot130^2\equiv 24\pmod{34}\\2^5\equiv-2\pmod{34}\Rightarrow2^{40}\equiv(-2)^8\equiv 18\pmod{34}\\15^4=50625=1488\cdot34+33\Rightarrow 15^4\equiv -1\pmod{34}\Rightarrow 15^{100}\equiv(-1)^{25}\equiv -1\pmod{34}$$
You have now the easy calculation $18(-1)-24$ modulo $34$

Comment: @rosa We can do this with simpler mental arithmetic if we first work mod $17$ then lift to mod $34$ - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\qquad \begin{align}{\rm mod}\ 17\!:\,\ n\, &\equiv\quad\   2^{40}\quad 15^{100}\  - \  63\cdot 130^2\\
&\equiv\  (2^4)^{10}((-2)^4)^{25}+5(-6)^2\\
 &\equiv\ (-1)^{10} (-1)^{25}\ +\ \ 5\,(2)\\
 &\equiv\  9\end{align}$

Thus $\ {\rm mod}\ 34\!:\,\ n \equiv 9\ $ or $\, n\equiv 9\!+\!17=26$

But our $\,n\,$ is clearly even, therefore $\,n\equiv 26\pmod{34}$